# Tracking of the sent emails using Marketing Cloud in Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, marketing-cloud-connect, history-tracking

We did some tests regarding the tracking of the sent email on the sales cloud, but we are not seeing any record in the contact page into the Individual Email Results and the Email Sends sections. I thought that thorugh the Marketing Cloud Connector i could see the tracking of the emails sent using MC.

Below are the detailed steps that we followed in our test: 1. First we created a custom Data Extension in the corporate BU populated using the query activity (the DE used in the query activity exists in the synchronised data extension list in the corporate BU). Then we moved it into the Shared DEs folder 2. Second, we created a filtered data extension using the custom DE mentioned above. 3. Finally, we sent a test email to the filtered DE. Knowing that we can see the tracking on the marketing cloud, but not on the sales cloud.

NB: The subscriber key used in the email studio feature and the primary key of these DEs is the Salesforce ID.
Could you explain me which are the reasons of this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see email results in Salesforce into "Individual Email Results" only if we send an email using a Salesforce DE (standard or filtered) or a Shared Salesforce DE (standard or filtered).
If we use Synchronized Data Extension or Custom DE, email tracking will not go back to Salesforce.